# Unable to remove pop-up immediately using selenium in python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, popupwindow, mouseclick-event, undetected-chromedriver

I am new to webscraping through Jupyter and want to scrape women's jackets from [url](https://www.backcountry.com/patagonia) only using CSS paths. I am using undetected chromedriver, when I load the url through selenium I get this pop-up discount [pop-up with html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCMa2.jpg). I tried to click on the cross ('X' button) using this code:-

```
actions = ActionChains(browser)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
close_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-reset _1g4dr'))).click()
```

and I am getting the following error :

*TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 close_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-reset _1g4dr'))).click()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:95, in WebDriverWait.until(self, method, message)
93     if time.monotonic() > end_time:
94         break
---> 95 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)*

It would be great if somebody can point out the problem and suggest a workaround on it. Thank you

I have tried 'move_by_offset' method and clicked outside of the pop-up window but it did not perform the operation.

Comment: your screenshot shows that the item you are targeting is outside of the popup.  You need to right-click on the "X" and choose "Inspect" to get to that element in inspector.  (sometimes you need to do that twice to get at the exact part...)  Or expand more of that div's contents...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate the precise popup that you saw. I suspect that the site has evolved since you posted this question. However, I got a similar popup (see screenshot below).

The button to close that popup has an `id` attribute.

[image]

This should make selecting it easy since you just use `#closeIconContainer`. Hopefully other popups on the site also have an ID on this element.

[image]